# How to change text color between two quotes in PowerShell window

Tags: powershell, settings

I can't change the text color between two quotes (now its color is durk-blue).
Where can I set up this setting or which command I have to execute?

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPj4g.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**PSReadline v1.x** (as shipped with *Windows PowerShell* v5.1 on Windows 10 and above):

```sh
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind String -ForegroundColor Green
```

**PSReadline v2.x** (as shipped with *PowerShell (Core)* v6.1+):

```sh
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ String = 'Green' }
```

Note:

- In both cases you can use the colors defined in the [`[ConsoleColor]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor) enumeration type.
- In v2.x you can alternatively use [VT (Virtual Terminal) / ANSI escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), which you *must* use if you want to set *background* colors.

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70580849/45375) and the [`Set-PSReadlineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption) documentation.