# How to change the individual syntax coloring in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

For whatever reason, in the following command in powershell,

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor Gray
```

I can't see anything after the dash.
[image]

I am guessing something is off with the colors and I am trying to change it.  The key seems to be picking the right TokenKind, which are listed (but not documented) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.tokenclassification?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).

Which `TokenKind` do I change in order to see text after the dash?

Comment: Comments in powershell are preceded by `#` or surrounded in block form by `<# #>`.  Indeed what you have found are explicitly named parameters (versus positionally-bound parameters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer by experimenting.  Posting it for the next person that runs into this issue.  The `TokenKind` is `Parameter`.

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind Parameter -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Comment: Indeed, a token that starts with `-` (informally called _dash_, but strictly speaking [_hyphen-minus_](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)) is a _parameter [name]_ in PowerShell. Do note that specifying colors changed in PSReadLine _v2_ (to be shipped with PowerShell Core 6.1.0), where a single `-Color` parameter now accepts a hashtable of token-kind-to-color mappings - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51758846/45375