# Powershell arrayslicing Get-PSReadLine

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, colors

trying to array slice the get-psreadlineoption command. I want to select all strings containing the word 'Color' and then input those to 'set-psreadline' to set all colors. I do not understand how this all works in powershell. It's an array, right? I can just loop over it like this:

`foreach($a in $i) { $i; if ($i -contains 'MemberColor') {$i;} }`

But that gives no output. I also cannot access it as an array:

`get-psreadlineoption[21..36]`
`get-psreadlineoption['EditMode']`

Does not work. Basically what I want to do is:

`foreach (get-psreadlines[21..36]) { $array = append(<string that contains 'Color'>) } foreach ($a in $array) { set-psreadline($a, ...)}`

How would I go about doing this?

(P.S. I just want to set all those colors to the same color in a concise manner as possible)

Comment: `get-psreadlineoption`, is a function not a (array) variable. To access the properties returned by the function: `(get-psreadlineoption).EditMode`

Comment: Cool, thanks. So how can I loop over those attributes?

Comment: `(get-psreadlineoption).ForEach{ $_ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a common question, how to loop through properties [Iterate over PSObject properties in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688708/iterate-over-psobject-properties-in-powershell).  You can also use get-member to get the property list.  You can also pipe to "select *color".

```
Get-PSReadLineOption | get-member *color | % name

CommandColor
CommentColor
ContinuationPromptColor
DefaultTokenColor
EmphasisColor
ErrorColor
KeywordColor
MemberColor
NumberColor
OperatorColor
ParameterColor
PredictionColor
SelectionColor
StringColor
TypeColor
VariableColor
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on what version of the [`PSReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline) module you're using:

- PSReadline *v2.x*, which ships with *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.
- PSReadline *v1.x*, which *Windows PowerShell* versions ship with in Windows 10+ / Windows Sever 2016+, although it is possible to install 2.x on demand in Windows PowerShell 5.0 and 5.1 (`Install-Module PSReadLine`)

Use `(Get-Module PSReadLine).Version.ToString()` to see which version you're using.

---

#### PSReadline *v2.x* solution:

To **get the names of all *color properties***, via filtering the names by those ending in `color` (case-insensitively), use *reflection*, which PowerShell facilitates via the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject):

```sh
(Get-PSReadLineOption).psobject.Properties.Name -like '*color'
```

Note:

- A quick way to print all property names of interest,  including their values, is to use
  [`Get-PSReadLineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline/get-psreadlineoption) `| Select-Object *color`. However, the result is a `[pscustomobject]`, not a *hashtable*, and in order to convert the former to the latter you'd again need the same technique shown below.
- However, as an **alternative to setting colors via `Set-PSReadLineOption`** (as shown below), you may also use the approach described for PSReadLine v1.x in the bottom section (e.g.,  `(Get-PSReadlineOption).CommentColor = 'DarkGray'`), in which case you can use the property names shown in the output from `Get-PSReadLineOption | Select-Object *color` as-is. Note that the property names differ between  v2.x and v1.x; also, as with `Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors` below, setting *background* colors requires the use of *VT escape sequences*.

*Caveat*: These **property names require a *transformation* in order to be usable as the keys of the hashtable you can pass to [`Set-PSReadLineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption) `-Colors`** (as of PSReadLine 2.1.0):

The suffix `Color` must be removed, and in the case of `DefaultTokenColor`, the suffix `TokenColor`, which the following [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation does:

```sh
(Get-PSReadLineOption).psobject.Properties.Name -like '*color' `
                                                -replace '(Token)?Color$'
```

This yields the following **color *key names*** (as of PSReadLine 2.1.0):

```
ContinuationPrompt
Default
Comment
Keyword
String
Operator
Variable
Command
Parameter
Type
Number
Member
Emphasis
Error
Selection
InlinePrediction
```

You can now pass a hashtable that *selectively* updates colors; e.g. the following sets the `Comment` (`CommentColor`) color to dark gray (while leaving all other colors untouched):

```sh
Set-PSReadLineOption -Color @{ Comment = 'DarkGray' }
```

A color value can either be:

- One of the values of the [`[ConsoleColor]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor) enumeration type; e.g. `[ConsoleColor]::DarkGray`, which you may pass as *string* `'DarkGray'`, as shown above.
- A [VT (Virtual Terminal) / ANSI escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Note that use of such sequences is a *must* if you want to **set the *background* color** for a given setting; e.g., the following sets the comment color to dark gray (`90`) on a white background (`47`)

  ```sh
  Set-PSReadLineOption -Color @{ Comment = "`e[90;47m" }
  ```

To create a hashtable comprising *all* color keys, using the current property values as a starting point, use the following:

```sh
$allColors = @{}
(Get-PSReadLineOption).psobject.Properties.
  Where({ $_.Name -like '*color' }).
  ForEach({ $allColors[$_.Name -replace '(Token)?Color$'] = $_.Value })
```

Note: When you print `$allColors`, the `Value` column may *appear* to be empty, but the values are there, in the form of - themselves invisible - Virtual Terminal (VT) control sequences.

---

#### PSReadline *v1.x* solution (*older versions* of *Windows PowerShell*):

Unlike the v2.x version:

- `Set-PSReadlineOption` in v1.x uses the *combination* of the `-TokenKind` and `-ForegroundColor` / `-BackgroundColor` parameters for the various colors and also, for general color settings, *individual parameters* (e.g. `-ErrorForegroundColor`) (rather than the single v2.x `-Colors` parameter that accepts a hashtable); also, all color settings are split into *foreground* and *background* values.
- The color values are limited to the values of the [`[ConsoleColor]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor) enumeration type, such as `'DarkGray'` (`[ConsoleColor]::DarkGray`)

For a ***unified* approach to setting colors**, you may forgo `Set-PSReadLineOption` and **directly set the properties of the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLineOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLineOptions) instance that `Get-PSReadLineOption` returns**.

For instance, the following sets the foreground color of comments to dark gray:

```sh
(Get-PSReadlineOption).CommentForegroundColor = 'DarkGray'
```

This is the equivalent of the following v1.x `Set-PSReadLineOption` call:

```sh
Set-PSReadLineOption -TokenKind Comment -ForegroundColor DarkGray
```

To get the names of all color-relevant properties, use the same approach as for v2.x:

```sh
(Get-PSReadLineOption).psobject.Properties.Name -like '*color'
```

This yields the following **color *property names***:

```
ContinuationPromptForegroundColor
ContinuationPromptBackgroundColor
DefaultTokenForegroundColor
CommentForegroundColor
KeywordForegroundColor
StringForegroundColor
OperatorForegroundColor
VariableForegroundColor
CommandForegroundColor
ParameterForegroundColor
TypeForegroundColor
NumberForegroundColor
MemberForegroundColor
DefaultTokenBackgroundColor
CommentBackgroundColor
KeywordBackgroundColor
StringBackgroundColor
OperatorBackgroundColor
VariableBackgroundColor
CommandBackgroundColor
ParameterBackgroundColor
TypeBackgroundColor
NumberBackgroundColor
MemberBackgroundColor
EmphasisForegroundColor
EmphasisBackgroundColor
ErrorForegroundColor
ErrorBackgroundColor
```